# Adding text to a list of divs without it effecting the other div's around it

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I feel like a fool for having to ask this question. But i'm having trouble with my html an css. I am trying to build a grid of icons, everything is great when I add the images, but when I add the text, depending on the font size for some, they shift the spacing of the boxes.

Anyways, here's what i've got

```
<div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span11 offset1">    
             <ul class="boxes">
                <li class="box">
                    <div class="inside-box">
                        {{ HTML::image('img/icons/Burton.png', 'burton-logo', array('class' => 'img-icon')) }}
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="box">
                    <div class="inside-box">
                        {{ HTML::image('img/icons/Male.png', 'burton-logo', array('class' => 'img-icon')) }}
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="box">
                    <div class="inside-box">
                        {{ HTML::image('img/icons/powder.png', 'burton-logo', array('class' => 'img-icon')) }}
                        <span class="terrain-text">POWDER</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="box">
                    <div class="inside-box">
                        {{ HTML::image('img/icons/camber.png', 'burton-logo', array('class' => 'img-icon')) }}
                        <span class="profile-text">camber</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="box">
                    <div class="inside-box">
                        {{ HTML::image('img/icons/flex-8.png', 'burton-logo', array('class' => 'img-icon')) }}
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="box">
                    <div class="inside-box">
                        {{ HTML::image('img/icons/Weight.png', 'burton-logo', array('class' => 'img-icon')) }}
                    </div>
                </li>
             </ul>     
           </div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap and Laravel, for those who aren't familiar with the `{{HTML::image}}` just consider it an `<img>` tag.

The css

```
.box{
  max-width: 250px;
  min-width: 250px;
  max-height: 166px;
  min-height: 166px;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1.5em;
  list-style-type: none;
 }
.inside-box{
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
 }
.inside-box h6{
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular';
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.inside-box img{
  margin-top: 35px;
}
.terrain-text{
  font-size: 40px;
}
.profile-text{
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

So again, the problem I'm having is with `.profile-text` and `.terrain-text` if I set there position to absolute then there spacing doesn't effect the other div's around them, but then I cannot center them using margin:auto. Is there a way to force the text not to effect the margins or spacing of anything around it?

Comment: Where do you want the text to show up in the end?

Comment: Oh and can you please create a fiddle? It makes messing around with your code so much easier :)

Comment: Yeah i'll do that, never made a fiddle before. So give me a few :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AeHu2/

Comment: I want to be able to move the text around basically anywhere in the box because the icon images are all different shapes and sizes. I just need for the text to not shift the boxes around, as you can see happening when you look at the fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to remove the elements from the normal flow, thus using absolute positioning is correct.

To achieve centering at the same time you set `left: 50%`, a fixed width for the element and negative half of that width as the left margin. Like so:

```
.caption {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You also need to set the parents element to which the centering refers to `position: relative`, in your case `.box` elements.

See working example based on your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AeHu2/1/